# How many probability measure are there?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm new to Probability Theory and I have learned that for a function $\mu$ to be a probability measure, it must satisfy a set of requirements.

I wonder whether for the same measurable space ($i.e.$ when we looking at the same thing/event), can we have 2 different probability measures and why ?

**EDIT**:
If we can have 2 different probability measures when "measure the same thing", is it counter-intuitive ? (like we have 2 different probability for the same thing to happen)

Comment: A probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ includes one probability measure. Do you means to ask about different probability measures on the same *measurable* space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$?

Comment: Sure. Let $\Omega$ be the space of outcomes for flipping a coin, with $T$ be the event that a tails is flipped and $H$ the event that a heads is flipped. Then we can have different probability measures based on whether or not the coin is biased. For example, $P,Q$ are different probability measures where $P(H)=P(T) = .5$ and $Q(T)=.8 = 1-Q(H)$.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have edited my question for more clarity! Could you have a look at it ?

Comment: @Hyperion: I think to actually see that the coin is biased, you have to first calculate the probability of head/tail (not the other way around). So maybe when calculating the probability of head/tail, we have 2 different "measure"

Comment: There are many issues of this general flavor in geometric measure theory and probability theory. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) and the resources cited therein. Sometimes one simply has to make choices about a measure, even with properties (such as invariance under a set of a transformations) are added as requirements beyond just being a probability measure. Intuitively, "what is the chance that X happens" depends upon assumptions about the process that may produce the outcome X.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly we can have many measures on a measurable space. For example, the counting measure assigns measure $n$ to any event of size $n$, and infinite measure otherwise (though that's not a probability measure). The "point mass at $x$" measure, for any $x \in \Omega$, is also a measure - it's even a probability measure, for each $x$. In that case, you're saying that an event only has any chance to happen if it contains one specific outcome, though you're varying which exact outcome it is.

The measure essentially determines the probability distribution. If you change the measure, that means you're redistributing the probability mass between events - for example, maybe you're biasing the dice differently.

There's a useful theorem which tells you when two measures are the same. If they assign finite measure to $\Omega$ (which probability measures always do), and they agree on a $\pi$-system (that is, a collection of sets closed under intersection) generating $\mathcal{F}$, then they agree everywhere. But otherwise you can have a huge variety of measures on the measurable space.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wonder if there are 2 probability measures for the same thing, it seems un-intuitive for me because I think there should be only 1 exact probability for 1 event to happen. Could you please explain to me more on this thought ? Thanks!

Comment: The measure essentially determines the probability distribution. If you change the measure, that means you're redistributing the probability mass between events - for example, maybe you're biasing the dice differently.

Comment: Oh. Now i understand. Could you please add this comment to your answer. I believe it is a good point to know for our newbies to probability theory.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are uncountably many possible ways to assign probabilities within the axioms of probability. For example in tossing a coin, you can assign to the outcome heads any real number $p\in[0,1]$. Then the outcome tails must be assigned the probability $1-p$ (unless you want to allow for some other outcomes such as the coin lands on its edge; or the coin rolls away and disappears and can't be found.)

However, in practical situations, the preferred probability distribution (or measure) is one that reflects (our view of) reality. We think the coin is fair, so heads and tails are both assigned a probability of $0.5$.  We certainly can assign a fair coin a different probability distribution; but then our probability distribution does not reflect reality, and will not be as useful.